# AWS Free Tier restrict usage to one region

Tags: amazon-web-services

Last month (I'm in the 3rd month of Free Tier) I tried to create a web app using one of the AWS wizards. This month I  noticed that I have run up a small bill even though I'm using the Free Tier and upon investigation found that I have instances running on another region on Elastic bean apart from my usual EC2. I suspect this to be the wizard but I could be wrong!

[Avoiding Unexpected Charges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/checklistforunwantedcharges.html) helped understanding what is going on but in your experience is there a way/setting to restrict usage entirely to one region to prevent accidental usage of resources?

Comment: There should be alert that will warn you when you leave "free tier".

Comment: I'm still within free tier(updated question as well), but thanks I'll check if for future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides a certain amount of unbilled usage of certain services in the first 12 months of an AWS account. Any usage outside of these limits will incur a charge.

If you are using the [Account Root User](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html), there is no way to restrict access to services.

Instead, you could create an **IAM user with permissions** that apply only to one region, and then login as that IAM user.

See: [Is it possible to restrict AWS users/accounts to a specific region?](https://serverfault.com/questions/589150/is-it-possible-to-restrict-aws-users-accounts-to-a-specific-region)

Also, keep an eye on the billing page in the console to be aware of charges and the amount of the Free Usage Tier remaining. You can also [create a billing alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html) to receive a notification when your account usage exceeds a given amount.

Comment: Gave it a go. It also restricts the wizards from spinning things up as expected. Thanks a lot.